Avoiding ee.Algorithms.If in Google Earth Engine Code Editor
Situation:
My colleague and I have made our first script in Google Earth Engine Code Editor that will be published as an Earth Engine App. The script shows 33 basin-polygons (imported as shapefile) that the user can click on, and a chart (the data in the chart is coming from a csv file) will appear for the chosen basin.
Problem:
We would like to avoid ee.Algorithms.If in our script, but we do not know how. In a previous question ee.FeatureCollection.filterBounds was suggested, but we could not find any examples of how to replace it with something that works in a similar way to how we use ee.Algorithms.If in our script.
Question:
Could someone please give an example of how to replace ee.Algorithms.If with ee.FeatureCollection.filterBounds or alternatives?
The whole script is shown here in this link:
Link to whole script
Here is the part of code that contains ee.Algorithms.If :
//Function for showing a correct chart when clicked inside a basin
function theyCLickedOnABasin(myBasin){
  var BasinName = ee.String(myBasin().first().get('Name')); // Defining the name of the basin when clicked on a polygon
    var p = ee.Algorithms.If(LastClicked.equals(BasinName),'',handleChart(myBasin,BasinName));
    LastClicked = BasinName;
}

// Function for reset the highlighting of polygon
function theyClickedAwayFromABasin(){
  var s = ee.Algorithms.If(LastClicked.equals(voidString),'',handleMapReset());
    LastClicked = voidString;



Your existing code doesn't work.  Can you repair it first?

This is the link for the whole script: link

I think you've got yourself tangled in some unecessary knots. It looks like those two functions just check for repeated clicks so you don't try to display the same chart twice or clear the map twice. Consider if that's worth the effort/extra code. But if you really, really want that functionality, I'd check later, once you've already needed to do some other getInfo calls.  (see the attached link, and specifically, check for dups around line 114).
Also, if you're trying to make elements appear and disappear during a click, then you're going to have to have some minimal amount of server/client transfer even though you want to avoid that as much as possible. You can minimize the amount of getInfo calls by getting "everything" you need in a single (or just a few) calls, and doing all the if/else stuff all on the client.  (See line 138 in the new code).
One thing that might help is knowing that most things will still work just fine with an empty collection.  So you don't need to do a conditional on its size; just let the empty layer get displayed and start through the chart handler regardless.
function handleMapClick(location) {
  var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([location.lon, location.lat])
  var myBasin = basin33.filterBounds(pt);
  
  var overlay = myBasin.style(highlightstyle);
  mapPanel.layers().set(1, ui.Map.Layer(overlay));

  handleChart(myBasin)
}

Then, in handleChart, you need to call getInfo for some additional information anyway; at that point you can check if the click wasn't on a basin.
var generateBasinChart = function (myBasin){ 
  var basinInfo = myBasin.first().getInfo()
  if (!basinInfo) {
    handleMapReset()
    return;
  }
  var BasinName = basinInfo.properties['Name']
  var chartname = basinInfo.properties['fullName']
  //Making a chart that shows all 4 data for a selected basin
  var basinNo = ee.String(BasinName.replace('Basin ', ''));

If breaks your encapsulation a little, but it's also way easier.
